# Error inflating class fragment - Simple Fragment code not working

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, layout-inflater, inflate

I am getting an error while running a simple fragment code on Android. It is not even displaying the layout and outputs an exception in logcat as Binary XML  file line  #7(for relative layout) and #8(with Linear layout)

> Error inflating class fragment.

**Here's my code:**

fragment1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:text="Heyy Thats Fragment 1"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />   

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragement1.java

```
package com.example.app1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
            return view;
    }
}
```

fragment2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Heyy Thats Fragment 2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment2.java

```
package com.example.app1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, 
                container, false);

                return view;
   }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentExampleActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.app1.Fragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment1" 
        class="com.example.app1.Fragment"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/text_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.app1.Fragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment2" 
        class="com.example.app1.Fragment2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.app1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and Manifest includes all 3 activities !! Fragment1, Fragment2 and MainActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just see the line in at 15 in activity_main.xml

replace

```
class="com.example.app1.Fragment" with class="com.example.app1.Fragment1"
```

"1" is missed

Comment: yah it worked... thanks a lot bro... that was such a stupid silly mistake one can do ! thank you very much :)